# Seeking Elevation Data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, kml

I'm trying to get elevation data and I have no idea where to look. I'm basically trying to get where land is above a certain elevation.

I'm primarily concerned with where land is above X' in Washington State and a kml file would be easiest for me to use.

Are there freely available websites or software programs where I can get this data?

Comment: You can download 30m SRTM Digital Elevation Model raster data here: https://dwtkns.com/srtm30m/  Just zoom/pan to you area of interest and click on the tiles.

Answer (score 3):

As [one of the comments](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/19681/seeking-elevation-data#comment20067_19681) mentioned, you can use the 30m-resolution data from the [Shuttle Radar Topography Mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Radar_Topography_Mission) that can be downloaded from various sites. Specifically for Washington State, you may find it more useful to look at the [list of links to WA elevation data](https://wagda.lib.washington.edu/data/geography/wa_state/#elevation) maintained by the Washington State Geospatial Data Archive, which includes higher-resolution data for parts of the state. Be prepared for the data to come in different formats, though – elevation data are usually stored as spatial rasters so KML is unlikely to be the format they're available in.

Comment: NRCS has their own Elevation on their site and just choose by state and they have either IFSAR or DEM https://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/

Answer (score 0):

Find in this [comment](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/19757/1614) information concerning the newly published (2021) Copernicus DEM - Global and European Digital Elevation Model (COP-DEM).