# High Resolution Digital Elevation Model for recent years

Tags: data-request, geospatial, remote-sensing

Where do I find SRTM or sentinel's high resolution DEMs for recent years? USGS is only giving the data till 2014, and I need at least for 2019. I've even tried sentinel hub but the cloud cover is too much for recent years.

Comment: Only thing you didn't mention location specifically ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the newly published (2021) Copernicus DEM - Global and European Digital Elevation Model (COP-DEM).

From the web site:

*It is a Digital Surface Model (DSM) which represents the surface of the Earth including buildings, infrastructure and vegetation. This DEM is derived from an edited DSM named WorldDEM. The Copernicus DEM is provided in 3 different instances named EEA-10, GLO-30 and GLO-90. The Copernicus DEM instances have varying geographical extent (European and global) and varying format (INSPIRE, DGED, DTED).*

- EEA-10: 0.3 (INSPIRE) 0.4 (DGED) - non-free
- **GLO-30**: 1.0 **Copernicus DSM30** (DGED) 1.0 (DTED):
- GLO-90: 3.0 (DGED) 3.0 (DTED)

Details, precision: https://spacedata.copernicus.eu/fr/dataset-details?articleId=394198

Download options:

- FTP at PRISM: https://spacedata.copernicus.eu/fr/data-access/discovery-and-download
- AWS: https://registry.opendata.aws/copernicus-dem/

*Edit 2022:*

You can download the Copernicus Digital Elevation Model covering Europe at different spatial resolutions from here (GeoTIFF files):

https://data.mundialis.de/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/search?keyword=Copernicus

For the download links, see the respective Zenodo DOI entries therein.